# Magento trying to get rid on horizontal line on topmenu of default theme

Tags: magento-1.9

I've spent hours trying to get rid of this line just above the navigation topmenu (Please see screenshot circle in red). I was just wondering if anyone know what I need to do to get rid of this line. Thanks

[image: site home page]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to work with the RWD theme if you're starting fresh? The 'base' theme isn't responsive at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the class `.header-container` remove `border-bottom: 1px solid #415966;`